# Querying for all results in Lucene IndexSearcher

Tags: java, lucene

I'm working with the SearchFiles class in Lucene's contrib/demo directory. Rather than search for results in paginated form, I want to be retrieve all documents that match the query. Is there a way to do this with the existing API (3.4)? It seems like all the search functions require an integer indicating the amount of hits to return.

The demo code looks like

```
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 5 * hitsPerPage);
ScoreDoc[] its = results.scoreDocs;
```

Which will only return a fixed number of results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own `Collector` and use it as `searcher.Search(query, new MyCollector());`

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Collector.html

Comment: the link above is DEAD this is why *link only answers suck!*

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1919289/932418 :) It disappeared after moving github.

Comment: a link to a project, which has been fixed btw, is different than a link to information/documentation that could be posted here in full.

Answer (score 6):

If using a Lucene Reader, i.e. the **IndexReader**, you can help yourself by writing

```
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, reader.numDocs());
```

This will ensure no result is omitted from the search.